# How to consume node-oidc-provider access_token with express?

Tags: node.js, oidc-provider

I believe it's silly question but how to use node-oidc-provider with express? So I got access_token on the client side, sent request with `Bearer {access_token}` and what's next? How can I obtain user from that token? I believe oidc-provider must have some middleware or anything which can be used for that but I didn't find any documentation on that topic. The only thing I found is [how to check if user is logged in](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/master/docs/README.md#how-to-display-on-the-website-of-the-op-itself-if-the-user-is-signed-in-or-not):

```
const ctx = provider.app.createContext(req, res)
const session = await provider.Session.get(ctx)
const signedIn = !!session.account
```

But it doesn't work for me and it looks like it's using cookies inside by some reason so session is null in that case.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Looks like the question on the github repo no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

You would make a request to the user_info endpoint using the access token in the authorization header. The url would be should in the `.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint of whatever route you attached the provider to.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. I created question in github repo, so more details regarding this issue available here: https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/issues/757